# Extract word out of string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract certain word out of a string using regex.

I got this code now and it works perfectly when i search for *

```
public static string Tagify(string value, string search, string htmlTag, bool clear = false)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\" + search + "([^)]*)\\" + search);
        var v = regex.Match(value);

        if (v.Groups[1].ToString() == "" || v.Groups[1].ToString() == value || clear == true)
        {
            return value.Replace(search, "");
        }

        return value.Replace(v.Groups[0].ToString(), "<" + htmlTag + ">" + v.Groups[1].ToString() + "</" + htmlTag + ">");
    }
```

But now I need to search for **, but unfortunately this does not work
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide some more exact specs and examples? Certainly, sounds like the simplest is `@"\*\*(.*?)\*\*"`, but the most efficient is`@"\*\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*)\*\*"`

Comment: Define "does not work", what *does* it do?

Comment: Why `([^)]*)` inside? Do you mean you want to exclude any `)` in between `**`s?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was it :D I just have to put a \ before every character. Thank you

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no I do not, I am not good in regex this is code from all around the web

Comment: Looking for this `@"\*([^\*]*)\*"`? [Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/jB2cQ7/1)

Comment: @shad0wk @"*([^*]*)*" gives the following error: parsing "*([^*]*)*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to use lazy dot matching in a capturing group.

Replace

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\" + search + "([^)]*)\\" + search);
```

with

```
Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("{0}(.*?){0}", Regex.Escape(search)));
```

Or in C#6.0

```
Regex regex = new Regex($"{Regex.Escape(search)}(.*?){Regex.Escape(search)}");
```

`Regex.Escape` will escape any special chars for you, no need to manually append `\` symbols.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is it.